# Why does selecting a 'Part' in my Angular *ngFor nested html-list display the corresponding 'Mechanism' instead?

Tags: angular, nested, html-lists, ngfor

I am new to Angular and am having an issue with a nested *ngFor and am hoping you can shed some light on the problem.

I have a main component (Portfolio), which has a nav component and detail component nested.
The main component triggers a service to make an api call to a backend db, and uses the data to populate both the nav component and detail component (when a selection is made - default display otherwise.

**PortfolioComponent.ts**

```
export class PortfolioComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Output() newChoiceEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter(true);

  private _choice: string = '-1';

  public get choice() {
    return this._choice;
  }
  public set choice(val: string) {
    this._choice = val;
    this.newChoiceEvent.emit(this._choice);
  }

  constructor (private portfolioService: PortfolioService) {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.portfolioService.getData().subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            this.portfolioService.mechanisms = data as Mechanism[];
          },
          error: (error: ErrorEvent) => { console.log('Error: ', error)}
      });
  }

  chooseAnother(choice: string) {
    this.choice = choice;
  }

}
```

**PortfolioComponent.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <smccaffrey-portfolionav (choiceEvent)="chooseAnother($event)" class="col col-md-4"></smccaffrey-portfolionav>
  <smccaffrey-projectdetail [choice]="choice" class="col col-md-8"></smccaffrey-projectdetail>
</div>
```

**PortfolioNavComponent.ts**

```
export class PortfolionavComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() choiceEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  selections:ListOption[] = [];

  constructor(private portfolioService: PortfolioService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selections = this.portfolioService.getSelections();
      //console.log('PortfolioNav: ', this.selections);
    }, 500);
  }

  chooseNew(id: string) {
    this.choiceEvent.emit(id);
  }

}
```

**PortfolioNavComponent.html**

```
<section class="flipped">
  <ul>
    <div *ngFor="let selection of selections" (click)="chooseNew(selection.id)">
      <li>{{selection.name}}</li>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let subselection of selection.parts" (click)="chooseNew(subselection.id)">{{subselection.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**PortfolioDetailComponent.ts**

```
export class ProjectdetailComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() choice: string = '-1';

  item!: Mechanism | Part;

  constructor (private portfolioService:PortfolioService) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    for (let prop in changes) {
      let change = changes[prop];
      if (prop === 'choice') {
        if(change.currentValue != '-1') {
          this.item = this.portfolioService.getSelectionDetail(change.currentValue);
          console.log('Change Value: ' + change.currentValue);
          console.log('Item: ' + this.item.name);
        }
      }
   }
  }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that when I select the 'Mechanism' in the nav the detail changes as expected, but when I select a 'Part' the 'Mechanism is displayed.

The console shows that the part selection does register, but immediately reverts to the 'Mechanism' it belongs to.
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sli98.png)

The expectation is that the selection the user makes is displayed in the detail component, for both mechanisms and parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further jiggery-pokery, I have come up with a 'solution' (quotes are because it feels kinda hacky to me).

Where I had the

```
<li>{{selection.name}}</li>
```

&&

```
<li>{{subSelection.name}}</li>
```

I added an anchor like this

```
<li><a [href]="">{{selection.name}}</a></li>
```

&&

```
<li><a [href]="">{{subSelection.name}}</a></li>
```

which has solved the issue of not displaying the Part.

I don't, however, know why this worked. Perhaps some of the more experienced dev's can weigh in and shed some light.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As stated in the answer, the 'solution' came from trial and error and I have no idea WHY it worked, just that it did